# Running a script in EMS

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, ems, tibco-business-works

I tried to get the ACLs of Q n Topics but one by one.
Can we run a script in EMS to get the ACLs of required queues r topics into a file.?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a text file with all your commands in it with each command on a new line.

example myscript.txt

```
showacl queue queue1
showacl queue queue2
```

On command line navigate to ems bin directory and call tibemsadmin executable with -script parameter and pass above created text file. example:

```
tibemsadmin -server tcp://localhost:7222 -script myscript.txt -user user -password pwd
```

The output would be shown on console you can redirect it to a text by appending >out.txt to above command.

*Don't forget to update the correct EMS server, username and password in the command.

Comment: Thank you Basit, it worked and i got all at one shot. But when connecting local ems server localhost , pwd not required.i hope i am right.

Comment: By default there is no password for the initial 'admin' user hence it works without the pwd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the EMS installation directory, then you can get the required details directly from the **acl.conf** file available in the installation directory.